# The set of regular points in an algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I saw the following fact in a paper I was reading and I was wondering if someone could provide a reference.  Let $K$ be a non-archimedean local field (say of characteristic $0$), and let $G$ be a connected reductive algebraic group over $K$.  Let $G_r(K)$ be the set of $K$-regular points in $G(K)$.  Then $G_r(K)$ is an open dense set in $G(K)$ (with respect to the topology induced by $K$).  I would also be interested in determining whether this also true when $K$ has positive characteristic.

Comment: What does it mean for a $K$-point of $G$ to be ``$K$-regular?"

Comment: A point $g \in G(K)$ is $K$-regular if the number of eigenvalues of $\mathrm{Ad}(g)$ of absolute value $1$ is minimal, where $\mathrm{Ad}$ is the adjoint representation of $G$.

Comment: The regularity condition is same as that in Borel(Linear Algebraic Groups) IV.12. May be it is worth looking at theorem 12.3.